# FIX response with this error: Value is incorrect (out of range) for this tag

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

When I send the order request on the FIX server as :

```
8=FIXT.1.1|9=179|35=D|34=34|49=135|52=20200206-04:52:04.406|56=PSE|1=11101401117577|11=1580964724079|38=1000|40=2|44=10.5|54=1|55=AGI|59=0|60=20200206-12:52:04.406|453=1|448=13501100|447=C|452=12|10=009|)
```

The response that I receive is:

```
8=FIXT.1.1|9=000362|35=8|49=PSE|56=135|34=34|57=13501100|52=20200206-04:52:04.533|37=NONE|11=1580964724079|453=4|448=13501999|447=C|452=11|448=13501999|447=C|452=36|448=13501100|447=C|452=12|448=135|447=C|452=1|17=1904|150=8|39=8|103=99|1=11101401117577|55=AGI|54=1|38=1000|44=10.5|59=0|528=F|151=0|14=0|60=20200206-04:52:04.356|58=(293): **Orders are not being accepted at this time|10=020|)**
```

With the PSE error as:

```
<20200206-04:52:04, FIXT.1.1:135->PSE, error> (Rejecting invalid message: quickfix.IncorrectTagValue: Value is incorrect (out of range) for this tag, field=528 field=528: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=362|35=8|34=34|49=PSE|52=20200206-04:52:04.533|56=135|57=13501100|1=11101401117577|11=1580964724079|14=0|17=1904|37=NONE|38=1000|39=8|44=10.5|54=1|55=AGI|58=(293): Orders are not being accepted at this time|59=0|60=20200206-04:52:04.356|103=99|150=8|151=0|528=F|453=4|448=13501999|447=C|452=11|448=13501999|447=C|452=36|448=13501100|447=C|452=12|448=135|447=C|452=1|10=132|)

<20200206-04:52:04, FIXT.1.1:135->PSE, error> **(Reject sent for Message 34: Value is incorrect (out of range) for this tag**, field=528:528)
```

According to the documentary the value for 1 should be 14 digit trading account(1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx) but when I give that, then I had receive the above error.So what value should be given for 1 so the response should be receive.

So what is the solution for this error?

Answer (score 4):

The flow is as follows:

- **you** send a NewOrderSingle
- **they** reply with an ExecutionReport that they don't accept orders at that time
- **you** (and **not** PSE) reject that ExecutionReport because tag 528 on the ExecutionReport that PSE sent contains a value that is not contained in your data dictionary.

What you need to do is either of

- Read PSE's rules of engagement (i.e. their FIX spec) and add all needed tags and values to your data dictionary.
- Configure your session to not validate incoming messages (setting `ValidateIncomingMessage=N`) but this means you would need to do validation by yourself if required. E.g. if you wanted to retrieve values from tag `150/ExecType` then you can be sure that only values which are allowed in the data dictionary reach your application. With disabled validation you would need to do these checks by yourself.

  - Alternatively you could set `RejectInvalidMessage=N` which also will not reject the message but only log the warning with the validation error.